# How do you make secure database calls once you authenticate a user with a JWT?

Tags: javascript, authentication

I am using auth0 for user logins, and I'm wondering once a user is logged in (has a valid JWT), how can I make sure my database calls are secure?

Right now, I have no protection, anyone can make requests.  I'm trying to look online, but I guess my search keywords are just wrong because I'm not sure what I should be searching for anyway.

Can someone help me out, or point me towards the right search terms?  Thanks!

Comment: you would need to use a server and confirm the token is valid to send the call to the database

Comment: hey.  so i am just using an express server that hooks up to my mongodb, and returns json for the various methods I have implemented.  so in this case, do I just use the JWT from auth and pass that along with each request I make to the API?

Comment: look into creating a middleware function that checks for the JWT, if expired, refresh token, if invalid, reject , if valid, then allow the user to hit the api endpoint, something like this might be useful https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt

Comment: thanks! looking now :)